# How to do Android animation timing

Tags: android, animation

Follows is an SSCCE to understand animation timing, extracted from a much more complicated example. What this example when completed should do is create a circle and change its fill color between red and green every second. Right now it just draws a red circle and then nothing else. I've tried placing Runnable, Timer, Thread, and Handler code in various locations but it never seems to do anything. Another problem I've encountered in run() methods is the need for references to Canvas and the current color and the only way I've obtained them is by creating member data for them which, especially in the case of Canvas, seems like a bad idea. For what I'm ultimately doing, rotation and translation of graphic objects, SampleView and the accompanying Canvas seems to be almost certainly necessary so I want to leave SampleView in place. I think that's part of the problem, most examples of animation I've encountered place the timing code in an Activity but that won't work cleanly since the inner View's canvas must be used to update the color (unless I'm missing something).

Inside run methods I used variations on code like this.

```
  if (color == Color.RED)
     color = Color.GREEN;
  else color = Color.RED;
  canvas.drawOval(rectF, p);
  hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
```

Those references to color and canvas have been a pain.

```
package com.example.circles;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
  }
  private static class SampleView extends View {
    public SampleView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      setFocusable(true);
      p = new Paint();
    }
    Paint    p;
    int      color;
    RectF    rectF = new RectF(0, 0, 50, 50);
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      color = Color.RED;
      p.setColor(color);
      canvas.drawOval(rectF, p);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Zero progress on this, this is an easy one, surely someone can answer?

Comment: Almost two months later and I still haven't got an answer to this. Surely someone can answer this basic question?